# How to connect to this FPGA board?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, header, development, ribbon-cable

I got this board from ebay, seemed to be a cheap deal. It is decent product from what I can say at this time.

[image]

The question is, what is the most appropriate way to connect a daughter board to this board on the wide shrouded male header? The obvious answer is to use a ribbon cable. However, won't that introduce a lot of parasitic capacitance? What decides how long the ribbon cable can be?

I have searched for 2x13 2.54mm female header socket for the daughter board. However, it seems that its dimensions are such that it wil not "come off" the edge of the PCB sufficiently to be pushed fully into the male header fully. Any ideas or pit-falls I need to look out for?

Comment: "won't that introduce a lot of parasitic capacitance" - as always, "it depends". It depends on what you connect up, on what you define to be a lot, on what frequency and type of signal you intend to use. Yes it may not be ideal for some signals, but bear in mind that good old fashioned IDE/PATA ran at 66MHz through a bog standard ribbon cable.

Comment: When you don't know how tall you are, you cannot be afraid of heights. Equal to that, you shall not fear parasitic capacitance, when you don't know (or don't tell) about the frequencies or needed rise times on the lines.

Comment: Not sure I follow the question, What is shown is a regular IDC-type 0.100" dual row connector. It will match to any 0.1" female header, PCB-mounted, edge mounted, or cable. The connector is usually good up to 100MHz clock-data rates, has an impedance of 80-100 Ohms. What is the question then?

Comment: Iy you *really* need to get high speed data out and you're worried about signal integrity, you could pull the ribbon cable off the plug and replace the wires with coax, I did that once and it was still working well at *600MHz*. Or, grab a scsi cable, I've seen some ribbon cable versions with twisted pairs, that'll maintain good signal integrity (provided you're using differential signalling).

Comment: Ali Chen, I don't know what data rate I can run with a ribbon cable, also there is the fact of propagation delay if long ribbon cable is used. If in your experience, the cable can "is usually good up to 100MHz clock-data rates" then I will not worry. It is just that I am rather paranoid since I have little experience in high speed PCB design and high speed digital and spend more time in planning and worrying about tiny things.

Comment: Wouldn't some of the connectors in this link work? https://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-headers-receptacles-female-sockets/1442548?FV=1600012%2C1640001%2C1680002%2Cfff40016%2Cfff802f4%2C114016f&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pbfree=0&rohs=0&k=header&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25&pkeyword=header

Answer (score 1):

The performance of the expansion connector should be the least of your concerns with that board.

There are almost no decoupling capacitors anywhere on that development board. It will be likely to malfunction at high frequencies, regardless of whether you're using the expansion connector or not.

Comment: For TQFP packages, all de-coupling is usually on the bottom (as for many other packaging). Do you state the lack of caps for the fact, or just guessing?

Comment: I (unfortunately) bought the Spartan-6 version of that board. There are no capacitors -- nor anything else, besides traces -- on the bottom side.

Comment: do you have a link? Do they come from the same "design house"?

Comment: Excuse me enlightened engineers, by decoupling do you mean decoupling the power supply? Why is that important when we talk about this connector?

Comment: @AliChen Both boards can be found on eBay by searching for the keyword "easyFPGA". They've got the same overall design, the same features, and the same logos on the board; it's quite obvious that they were designed by the same person or group.

Comment: @quantum231 The lack of any decoupling capacitors close to the FPGA will cause it to malfunction when running larger, higher-frequency designs. This effect will come into play well before the connector you're referring to in your question becomes a limitation.

Comment: @quantum231, de-coupling has two meanings/purposes. One is to make the local power supply stable, remove externally introduced ripples and noise. The other set of capacitors needs to be placed near FPGA side. When a FPGA runs internal code, the consumption fluctuates and may contain spikes. The role  of decoupling caps is to supply this occasional starvation locally via very short wires, so the internal voltage does not drop below unsafe level. If these caps are missing, the FPGA will not work reliably.

Comment: @AliChen The *design house* is [here](http://www.logifind.com/fpga-cpld-dsp/altera-cyclone-iv-fpga-development-board-ep4ce6e22c8n-1172.html). "Schematics" (I have to put that in quotes) are available [here](https://od.lk/fl/NDVfMzYyMzg5Xw). At least in the schematics, there are some decoupling caps. I agree with duskwuff, this seems to be a low quality board.

Comment: @Andreas There are a couple of "decoupling" capacitors on the board. They're just all in the wrong places -- there are two near the expansion connector, one next to the buzzer, several near the SPI flash chips and next to the regulators...